# Linux container initialization script utilizing systemd

Tags: systemd, systemd-nspawn

I am trying to make a template filesystem for my systemd-nspawn container. The container filesystem will be cloned from this template by btrfs snapshot. I needs the container to run a initialization script when the container first boot. After reading many documents, I write the following systemd unit.

*/etc/systemd/system/init-script.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=Init script
Wants=network-online.target first-boot-complete.target
After=network-online.target
Before=first-boot-complete.target
ConditionFirstBoot=yes

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/root/init-script.sh
```

But I am still not very clear on systemd boot process, I am not sure which systemd target should pull in my init-script.service.

Should I use

```
[Unit]
DefaultDependencies=no

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```

or

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The content of the initialization script is the commands to setup the service of that container, for example, setup a Apache reverse proxy or Postfix.